# É correto utilizar useCallback dentro de um hook customizado?

Tags: react, react-hooks

Estou tendo problemas para utilizar hooks customizados dentro do **useEffect**, em especial, quando defino dentro do **useEffect** métodos do hook customizado que alteram o seu estado interno. Diante deste problema me deparei com as seguintes situações.

**Modelo utilizado para o exemplo**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const useCounter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);
  const methods = {
    increment: () => setCount((prev) => prev + 1),
  };
  return { count, ...methods };
};

const Counter: React.FC = (props) => {
  const { count, increment } = useCounter();
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{count}</h3>
      <button onClick={() => increment()}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Counter;
```

Supondo que seja necessário executar ***"increment"*** logo na montagem do componente. Isso pode ser feito utilizando o **useEffect** passando um array de dependências vazio.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    increment();
    console.log("INCREMENT ON MOUNT...");
  }, []);
```

No entanto, executando o código acima é obtido o aviso do **esLint** que ***"increment"*** deve ser adicionado ao array de dependências ou removido do **useEffect**.

> Line 17:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency:
> 'increment'. Either include it or remove the dependency array
> react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

**Então, faz-se as devidas alterações:**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    increment();
    console.log("LOOPING...");
  }, [increment]);
```

Agora com ***"increment"*** adicionado ao array de dependências do **useEffect** o aviso do **esLint** desaparece, porém, a aplicação entra em looping.

**Tentativas de solução**

Logo de inicio achei que esse problema podia estar relacionado há falta de igualdade referencial entre as funções, já que as mesmas são recriadas a cada render. Por isso, assim que obtive o problema tentei resolve-lo utilizando o **useCallback**, uma vez que ele fornece uma igualdade referencial da função entre cada render do componente;

```
  const safeIncrement = useCallback(() => increment(), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    safeIncrement();
    console.log("NO LOOPING...");
  }, [safeIncrement]);
```

A mudança me retornou um segundo aviso, desta vez solicitando que ***"increment"*** fosse passado como dependência do **useCallback**:

> Line 14:56:  React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency:
> 'increment'. Either include it or remove the dependency array
> react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Alteração feita, e voa lá, aplicação em looping novamente:

```
  const safeIncrement = useCallback(() => increment(), [increment]);

  useEffect(() => {
    safeIncrement();
    console.log("LOOPING...");
  }, [safeIncrement]);
```

**Passando o useCallback para o hook customizado**

```
const useCounter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);
  const methods = {
    increment: useCallback(() => setCount((prev) => prev + 1), []),
  };
  return { count, ...methods };
};
```

Passei então o **useCallback** para dentro do hook customizado e isso pareceu funcionar, nenhum aviso, nem looping dessa vez... A questão é que não sei se a prática é correta, nunca fiz, nem vi ninguém fazendo, além disso minha abordagem geral pode estar errada. Se alguém poder me passar um feedback a respeito dessa prática desde já lhe agradeço :)

**Para conferir a sequência dos Renders(parece estar ocorrendo corretamente):**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

const useCounter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);
  const methods = {
    increment: useCallback(() => {
      setCount((prev) => prev + 1);
      console.log("RENDER - INCREMENT");
    }, []),
  };
  return { count, ...methods };
};

const Counter: React.FC = (props) => {
  const { count, increment } = useCounter();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("RENDER - APP");
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    increment();
  }, [increment]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{count}</h3>
      <button onClick={() => increment()}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Counter;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que o seu problema está em:

```
const useCounter = () => {

  const methods = {    // DESSA MANEIRA
     ...               // ESSA VARIÁVEL VAI SER SEMPRE RECRIADA E 
  };                   // SUA REFERÊNCIA VAI MUDAR A CADA render DE useCounter
};
```

Não coloque o `useCallback` dentro do object `methods`. Não sei se vai funcionar, mas isso vai contra uma das regras dos hooks e não é uma boa prática.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é uma das formas de fazer:

```js
const useCounter = () => {
  const [count,setCount] = React.useState(0);
  
  const increment = React.useCallback(() => setCount((prevState) => prevState + 1),[]);
  
  return ({
    count, increment
  });
  
};

function App() {

  const { count, increment } = useCounter();

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Count: {count} </div>
      <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Se você realmente quiser utilizar um objeto chamado `methods`, você pode fazer assim:

- `useCallback` garante que a referência de `increment` não muda.
- `useRef` garante que a referência de `methods` não muda.

```js
const useCounter = () => {
  const [count,setCount] = React.useState(0);
  
  const increment = React.useCallback(() => setCount((prevState) => prevState + 1),[]);
  
  const methods = React.useRef({
    increment
  });
 
  return ({
    count, 
    ...methods.current
  });
  
};

function App() {

  const { count, increment } = useCounter();

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Count: {count} </div>
      <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```